# "Request have unknown arguments: [options]"

Tags: node.js, xmpp, ejabberd

my body

const data = JSON.stringify({
name: jid_topic_room,
service: "conference.localhost",
host: "localhost",
options: [
{
name: "title",
value: topic_name
}
]
});
var options = {
protocol: "http:",
host: "::1",
port: 5443,
path: "/api/create_room",
method: "POST",
headers: {
"Content-Type": "application/json",
"Content-Length": data.length,
},
};
var callback = function (response) {
var message = "";
response.on("data", function (buffer) {
message = buffer.toString();
});
response.on("end", function () {
console.log(message);
});
};
var request = http.request(options, callback);
request.on("error", function (err) {
console.log("Error with request", err.message);
});
request.write(data);
request.end();

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before you ask a question. Its not clear what you are asking, code is not formatted etc.

Answer (score 0):

thanks geeks i found solution instead of using  /api/create_room_with_opts i was using  /api/create_room